# Code Push breaking jest tests for react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, jestjs, react-native-code-push

I have configured an app for code-push, it works well except for jest tests. It fails in rendering app for this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'CheckFrequency' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (app/index.js:7:66)
  at Object.<anonymous> (index.ios.js:5:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/index.ios.js:4:12)
```

in this line:

```
const codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.MANUAL };
```

The test code is:

```
import App from '../index.ios';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
      <App />,
  );
});
```

Comment: You need to create a [mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html) for CodePush

Comment: codePush varibale is not defined or not a json'

Comment: @Assem Chelli did you resolve your issues? Running into something similar myself...

Comment: @TomHall not yet

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm also running into this.

Comment: @Olivia not yet

Comment: @BigOther Try my solution, if you still haven't fixed this, it worked quite well for me. :)

Answer (score 11):

I came across this problem while integrating `codePush` into the React Native app I am currently working on. What worked for me was:

1. Creating a file `__mocks__/react-native-code-push.js`.

Adding the following code to it:

```
const codePush = {
  InstallMode: {ON_NEXT_RESTART: 'ON_APP_RESTART'},
  CheckFrequency: {ON_APP_RESUME: 'ON_APP_RESUME'}
};

const cb = _ => app => app;
Object.assign(cb, codePush);
export default cb;
```

On my `index.js` file, I have:

```
import codePush from 'react-native-code-push';
import MyApp from './src/'

const codePushOptions = {
  installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESTART,
  checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME
};

export default codePush(codePushOptions)(MyApp);
```

Comment: luizParreira, where did you create the `__mocks__` directory? Did you have to link it anywhere?

Comment: made `__mocks__` directory in root. https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html

Answer (score 9):

Similar to what [Tom Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705800/tom-hall) describes, this mock does work for me:

```
jest.mock('react-native-code-push', () => {
  const cp = (_: any) => (app: any) => app;
  Object.assign(cp, {
    InstallMode: {},
    CheckFrequency: {},
    SyncStatus: {},
    UpdateState: {},
    DeploymentStatus: {},
    DEFAULT_UPDATE_DIALOG: {},

    checkForUpdate: jest.fn(),
    codePushify: jest.fn(),
    getConfiguration: jest.fn(),
    getCurrentPackage: jest.fn(),
    getUpdateMetadata: jest.fn(),
    log: jest.fn(),
    notifyAppReady: jest.fn(),
    notifyApplicationReady: jest.fn(),
    sync: jest.fn(),
  });
  return cp;
});
```

Comment: Why the currying? It does not pass like that.  After modifying to `const cp = (app: any) => app;` it passes.

Answer (score 1):

In your tests, underneath your `import App from '../index.ios';`, add the following:

```
jest.mock('react-native-code-push', () => {
    return jest.fn(() => ({
        InstallMode: jest.fn(),
        CheckFrequency: jest.fn(),
        CodePushComponent: jest.fn(),
        codePushify: jest.fn()
    }));
});
```

Comment: I believe this will still result in the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'MANUAL' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You need a mock up for `code-push` to work, this line `CodePush.CheckFrequency.MANUAL` will always produce the `null`.